# How to convert binary datatype to IP string

Tags: reporting-services, vertica

We have stored IP address as binary in Vertica database.  How to convert them into IP address like xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx to display in SSRS Report?

Comment: Can you show us how the IP is stored? IPv4, IPv6, contains decimals, etc... See [Binary Data Types](https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#11033.htm) for more info. If you were using an IPv6 address, Vertica has built in functions to convert to/from binary: [V6_ATON](https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#11377_1.htm) & [V6_NTOA](https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#11378_1.htm)

Comment: Thanks FreshPrinceOfS.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if there is an "officially approved" method so if no-one else suggests one I guess you'd be looking for a hack. If so, try and extract a binary IP address and pass it through a hex-dumper and post what you get, along with the corresponding IP address if possible.

Unix tool for hex-dump is *od*, use it like this:

```
od -x somefile
```

or

```
echo something | od -x
```

Answer (score 0):

The mask in your post suggests that you have IPv4 addresses. So a simple example would be (assuming network by order):

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(HEX_TO_INTEGER(TO_HEX(HEX_TO_BINARY('a0b0c0d0'))));
```

Where `HEX_TO_BINARY('a0b0c0d0')` is just for sake of the demonstration.

For IPv6, as Kermit suggested in his comment, use V6_NTOA.